# Adding latitude and Longitude into a Google Places URL in Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm working on finding nearby places in my Android app. I can find the current latitude and longitude as a double and then converting the double into a string to display in a textview (just to prove to myself that it's working). The problem I'm having is passing the lat. & long. strings into the Places URL. The URL displays the JSON data when I use a fixed value string for the lat. and long., but it returns INVALID_REQUEST when I try to pass the obtained doubles converted into strings into the URL. Here's what it looks like:

```
    Location currentLocation;
double currLatitude;
double currLongitude;
String latString; 
String longiString;
String latString2 = "30.4335320";
String longiString2 = "-97.9822360";

    towers = locMan.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    currentLocation = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(towers);
    currLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
    currLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
    latString = String.valueOf(currLatitude);
    longiString = String.valueOf(currLongitude);
    latiText.setText(latString);
    longiText.setText(longiString);
```

I think maybe I'm not parsing the doubles into strings correctly here?

```
        latString = String.valueOf(currLatitude);
    longiString = String.valueOf(currLongitude);
```

because in the below URL when I use the parsed values `latString, longiString` that's when I get INVALID_REQUEST, but if I pass `latString2, longiString2`, which are given values, the URL displays the JSON data. Here's the URL:

```
    String tURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?"
+ "location=" + latString + "," + longiString
+ "&radius=25000&"
+ "types=church&name=baptist&sensor=false&key="
+ myPlaceKey;
```

Comment: Can you print both url, when they are constructed with `latString` and `latString2`, paste the resultant URL here.

Answer (score 0):

I fugured it out. My problem was that the activity that returned the URL was a separate Activity from the URL string builder. And the URL returning Activity did not call the method where I obtained the latitude and longitude, so I think the URL the returning Activity obtained basically had "null" for the coordinates. So I combined the two Activities so now the coordinates are obtained, then the URL is built, then the URL result is displayed in a textview, all in one Activity - and it WORKS! I'm such an idiot!